# What happens when vampires use "hypnotic gaze"?

Tags: the-sims-3, sims-3-supernatural

In The Sims 3 Supernatural a vampire sim can use "hypnotic gaze" interaction when talking to other people.
One would expect it to hypnotize the sim it was used on or something but as far as I can tell it doesn't do anything at all.

What does this "hypnotic gaze" interaction do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you have to do is hunt and then the tartget you just hunted for you hypenotic gaze and when he/she is doing that selelect for the next action for your sim to do is bite then he/she should successfully bite if not try it again

Answer (score 2):

> Have you ever sent your vampire out for a quick bite, only to be
>   rejected by your chosen victim? With Hypnotic Gaze your vampire can
>   **convince strangers that being bitten seems like a great idea**.

in [www.thesims3.com/community](http://www.thesims3.com/community/blog.html?blogid=447688)

Comment: I tested it and this doesn't seem to work. They refuse you even after you use hypnotic gaze on them.

Answer (score -2):

As far as I can tell it becomes easier to make friends after using the hypnotic gaze, once they become friends you can drink from them.